# How to replace a @JoinColumn with a hardcoded value?

Tags: java, jpa

For more context, please see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824565/jpa-fk-on-subset-of-pk-table-to-eliminate-composite-key-need).

I want to join my `Employee` entity class to `Code` entity class but the Code PK is composite (DOMAIN, CODE) because it lists many different code domains, yet the codes that go in the Employee class/table are all from within a single domain, eliminating the need to have a domain field in the Employee class/table (because it would always be the same).

Can I join *Employee* to *Code* by using the CODE field in the *Employee* table and a hardcoded value (e.g. *EMP_TYPE*) instead of a redundant column?

If my *Employee* class/table did indeed have that redundant column, I would join it like this:

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_TYPE_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "DOMAIN", referencedColumnName = "DOMAIN)})
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Code sharedStatute;
```

but I REALLY don't want to have that extra column in the DB and in the class because it will always be the same.

What I am trying to accomplish would be equivalent to the following in SQL:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, c.description as emp_type
FROM Employee e JOIN Code c
ON e.emp_type_code = c.code
WHERE c.domain = 'EMP_TYPE'
```

as opposed to adding a field `domain` in the Employee table and populating EVERY SINGLE RECORD with the same value ('EMP_TYPE') and then doing:

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, c.description as emp_type
FROM Employee e JOIN Code c
ON e.emp_type_code = c.code
AND e.domain = c.domain
```

The former is more efficient because it saves me from having to have a redundant field.  So what I am trying to do is the same thing but in `JPA`.

Some of you may say something to the effect of "why not have a separate lookup table for each code" but I think that's a terrible idea and causes cluttering of DB tables and corresponding application entities.  It is much better to have a single code lookup table partitioned by code type (or domain).

Comment: See this question instead
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924928/hibernate-how-to-use-a-constant-as-part-of-composite-foreign-reference

Answer (score 6):

This should work?

```
@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_TYPE_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
@Where(clause = "domain = 'EMP_TYPE'")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Code sharedStatute;
```

Comment: where do you get the `@Where` annotation from ?  Doesn't seem to be under `javax.persistence`

Comment: It's a hibernate feature, I thought it had made it into JPA2, but apparently not.

Comment: unfortunately not...  is there a different way to accomplish the same thing in JPA ?

Comment: The only way I can think of would be make an 'EmployeeDomainCode' a subclass of 'Code' and use the Domain column as the discriminator value.

Comment: e.g. can I create a 'pseudo' column in the entity whose value is hard coded to 'EMP_TYPE' and then join on that as opposed to having to have an actual table column?

Comment: This works with a caveat: When I try to do this twice in the same entity but with different where clauses I get 'able with that name [MyJoinTable] already associated with entity'

There is a @WhereJoinTable annotation I can try out

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Apparantly this solution is OpenJPA only.

There is a way to do this with javax.persistence annotations only:

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_TYPE_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_TABLE_NAME.DOMAIN", referencedColumnName = "'EMP_TYPE'")})
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Code sharedStatute;
```

Note the **single** quotes in the referencedColumnName, this is the String value you are looking for.

There is a downside however, when you have multiple Code objects in your entity, the join on DOMAIN will be done only once in jpa, giving bad results. At the moment I circumvent this by making those field load lazily, but that's not ideal.

More information [here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html).

Comment: I can explain the downvote: Single quoted strings do not exist in Java. Single quotes are used for single characters only. Maybe you meant something like: `referenceColumnName = "'EMP_TYPE'"`?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I messed up when I made my working code look more like what the asker was using. Wish someone told me about the typo ':-)

Comment: Also, that seems to be specific to OpenJPA (according to the link you gave). I've just tried to do just that with Hibernate 5, and I get `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: '1' in OBJECT_PARAM`

Comment: Yes this method doesn't work with Hibernate "Unable to find column with logical name:'EMP_TYPE'