# JPA many-to-one with constant values in referenced table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm doing Spring Boot project and use spring-boot-jpa (Hibernate implementation). I'm having trouble configuring following relation between entities.

Let's assume I need many-to-one (and reversly one-to-many) relation between two tables (MySQL in this example, `table1` logically stores description for codes in various other tables) :

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `ref_table` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   `ref_column` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   `code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   `description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE INDEX `u_composite1` (`ref_table` ASC, `ref_column` ASC, `code` ASC));

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `field1` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
   `code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

The way I join these two tables in SQL is like this:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.description 
FROM table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1 
  ON    ( t1.ref_table = 'table2'
      AND t1.ref_column = 'code' 
      AND t1.code = t2.code);
```

So, I created entities like this (minus the getters an setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Table1  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String code;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "ref_column", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String refColumn;

    @Column(name = "ref_table", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String refTable;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table1")
    private List<Table2> table2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class Table2  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private int id;

   @Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
   private String field1;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @Column(name = "code")
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "code", nullable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "'table2'", referencedColumnName = "ref_table", nullable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "'code'", referencedColumnName = "ref_column", nullable = false, updatable = false)
   })
   private Table1 table1;

}
```

But it doesn't work. :(

Can this kind of relation even be defined in JPA?
If so, please, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pertaining to the "join with constant values" problem I managed to make it work using the @Where Hibernate annotation:

- [How to replace a @JoinColumn with a hardcoded value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831357/how-to-replace-a-joincolumn-with-a-hardcoded-value)

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "a")
  public class A {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      public long id;

      @OneToMany
      @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
      @Where(clause = "blah = 'CONSTANT_VALUE'")
      public Set<B> b;

      protected A() {}
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "b")
  public class B {
      @Id
      @Column(nullable = false)
      public Long id;

      @Column(nullable = false)
      public String blah;

      protected B() {}
  }
  ```